# Is ImageFigure() Constructor present in graphiti.js like draw2d?

Tags: draw2d, graphiti-js

i found one method ImageFigure() in draw2d. So i want to know is it presnt in graphiti.js also. If it present in graphiti then it solves my problem on grouping object.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageShape or ImageFigure is not part of the current graphiti version. Graphiti tries to implement almost all functions/object from Draw2D......but it requires some time.